# Search for substring inclusive of carriage return and newline characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a Python script which is communicating with another application (a debugger connected to an embedded target to be exact) using a socket connection.

The responses from the debugger can vary in length and can span multiple lines but they always end with either `True\r\n` or `False\r\n`. I want to capture `True` or `False` including the newline characters.

The regular expression I'm using (e.g. `r'^[.]+|[\r]+|[\n]+(True\r\n)$'` for True) seems to work when tested on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wc7a4G/1) but only returns `\r` when run with Python.

Sample code with a sample response string:

```
import re  
sample_response = 'var0 = 0x00000001\r\nTrue\r\n'
re_true = re.compile(r'^[.]+|[\r]+|[\n]+(True\r\n)$')
print re_true.search(sample_response).group(0) # Will print out '\r'
```

I know there is something fundamentally wrong with the regex I'm using. I've also tried positive lookbehind as shown below and that seems to work but I'm not sure if this is the **correct** way to do this:

```
import re  
sample_response = 'var0 = 0x00000001\r\nTrue\r\n'
re_true = re.compile(r'(?<=(True\r\n))')
print re_true.search(sample_response).group(0) # Will print out ''
print re_true.search(sample_response).group(1) # Will print out 'True\r\n'
```

Comment: Yes, but regex101 does not have `\r`, its line break style is `\n`. Your regex  matches `\r` in your input before trying the `True` part and it is the first alternative that wins in NFA regex. Try `re.findall` or reconsider the requirements.

Comment: Yup, I used \n on regex101.com for testing my regex...regardless of that, the regex101 reference was probably TMI and is not really my question :)

Comment: I'll test with findall...thanks!

Comment: Then why use alternation at all? You say you need to match `True\r\n` or `False\r\n` - use `r'[\r\n]*\b(?:True|False)[\r\n]*$'` with `re.search`.

Comment: Yup that seems to be working...the alternation in the beginning was to _ignore_ any characters or newlines etc. before the terminating True or False...but that was probably the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you need to match `True\r\n` or `False\r\n`, then the `^[.]+|[\r]+|` in your pattern is redundant. Use

```
re.search(r'[\r\n]*\b(?:True|False)[\r\n]*$', s)
```

Or leave out the initial `[\r\n]*` if you need no line breaks before `True` or `False`.

**Details**:

- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or LF symbols
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:True|False)` - either `True` or `False` as whole words
- `[\r\n]*` - as above
- `$` - end of string.